# Problem "I created a plugin to connect a sale with Lemon Squeezy and the creation of an account with Wordpress"

Tags: wordpress

I created a plugin to connect a sale with Lemon Squeezy and the creation of an account with Wordpress
but I have the {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}

The code is:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('lemon-squeezy/v1', '/subscription/purchase', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'create_wordpress_account_and_set_role',
    ));
```

```
register_rest_route('lemon-squeezy/v1', '/subscription/cancel', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'change_wordpress_role_on_subscription_cancel',
    ));
});
```